# PHP/mysql problem with output of query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table in my database:

```
classes

id | classname | 


grades 

id | class_id | grade | date
```

I need to get the average of the grades and the latest grade based on the date + the correct classname.

I have this query but this doesn't output the correct classnames...

```
SELECT 
                AVG(grade),
                classes.classname,
                grades.grade,
                MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),'date')))
                FROM 
                grades, classes

                GROUP BY
                grades.grade_id

                ORDER BY grades.date DESC
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem a bit more?

Comment: I need to get a output like English | 8.0 (average) | 7.5 (latest)

Comment: Huh, what is cijfers?  You aren't selecting from a table with this name...

Comment: fixt the cijfer.datum, i translated the names.. (really badly though)

Comment: "cijfers" is Dutch for grades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seemed a little vauge, so Im answering my interpretation of your question.

You didnt demonstrate what you got, but, Im going to guess you got a list of grades with an average by class, not classes with grades..

So, while I think theres a few questions in there. First.

```
select avg(grade), classname from classes 
left join grade on classes.id = grades.class_id 
group by classname
```

Should give you the average grade by class.

What is cijfers? you didnt really include much about that yet you also asked it to average it somehow.

Comment: "cijfers" is the Dutch word for grades. :)  Your solution should be correct; the issue is that the group by can't work.

Comment: Correct, and I can't explain my problem that well in english. sorry fot that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, AVG(cijfer) is actually referencing nothing. You need to assign the AVG() to a variable like this:

```
AVG(grade) AS avgrade
```

Perhaps you could try a query like this:

```
SELECT AVG(grade) as average FROM grades, class_id AS cid, (SELECT classname FROM classes WHERE id=cid) AS cname FROM grades ORDER BY date DESC GROUP BY cname;
```

Hows that work out?

Comment: updated answer as I forgot to assign class name to a variable

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate doing someone's homework for them,   This seems to work for me:

```
select a.classname, AVG(b.grade) AS "Avg Grade",
       c.grade as "Most Recent Grade", c.grade_date as "Most Recent Grade Date"
from classes a, grades b, grades c
where a.id = b.class_id
AND c.class_id = a.id
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT d.grade_date FROM grades d
     WHERE d.class_id = c.class_id
     AND   d.grade_date > c.grade_date)
group by a.classname, c.grade, c.grade_date;
```